# I am trying to read the first line in my .txt document in to my program?

Tags: java, file

I have this written so far, I am just doing a few practice codes from my text book. I cant seem to get this to read the first line in my .txt .

```
/**
* 
*/
import java.util.Scanner; //needed for scanner class
import java.io.*; //needed for File I/O classes

/**
* @author Megan
*
*/
public class Pres {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name of file: C:/User/Frances/Documents/USPres.txt");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File("C:/User/Frances/Documents/USPres.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    String line = inputFile.nextLine();

    System.out.println("The first line in the file is: ");
    System.out.println(line);

    inputFile.close();


}

}
```

I believe it has to do with this portion of the code:

```
String line = inputFile.nextLine();
```

I am not quite sure what to type into the (), if I should type anything at all. I could be wrong. My textbook isn't to clear about the proper format. If you could help, please and thank you. :)

Comment: Please tell the details of what's not working.

Comment: Try to check inputFile.hasNextLine() is true?

Comment: Just to help clarify the issue, the first three lines in your main method aren't doing anything related to reading from a file and can be removed: "Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name of file: C:/User/Frances/Documents/USPres.txt");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
"

Answer (score 0):

To read txt file do this:

```
String line = "";
BufferedReader in = null;

try {
  in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something here
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    in.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

It will read all lines in the text but since it's practice go ahead and try to figure out how to read just one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Pres {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // BufferedReader  is best for read line from file or else
        BufferedReader Bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your_filename_or_path.txt"));
        // get first line from file
        String firstLinetext = Bfr .readLine();
        System.out.println(firstLinetext ); // print first line
    }
}
```